# Swift: UIDocumentInteractionController is not working?

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentinteraction

UIDocumentInteractionController is not working with large pdf files with multiple pages.

Here in my code,

```
      var docController:UIDocumentInteractionController!
```

...

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async (execute: { [weak self] in

            self?.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: pdfFileURL!)
            self?.docController.delegate = self
            self?.docController.name = pdfFileURL?.lastPathComponent
            self?.docController.presentPreview(animated: true)
    })
```

and delegate method,

```
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
    return self
}
```

This is the warning in console,

> 2017-05-26 12:46:51.178894 MyApp [3350:1136818] [default] View service did terminate with error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted} #Remote

Below attached is the blank image,

[image]

Please help me out thanks.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm in a similar boat. I have everything set correctly but when I call `presentPreview(animated:)` it returns false every time. It is also not calling my delegate method `documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview`

Answer (score 4):

Try Like This:

Declare :  `var interaction: UIDocumentInteractionController?`

Then add

```
 interaction = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: URL(string: "<PDF FILE PATH>")!)
 interaction.delegate = self
 interaction.presentPreview(animated: true) // IF SHOW DIRECT
```

OR if need any suggestion popup

```
interaction.presentOpenInMenu(from: /*<SOURCE BUTTON FRAME>*/, in: self.view, animated: true)
```

Implement Delegate -> `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate`

```
public func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
    return self
}

public func documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) {
    interaction = nil
}
```

Comment: `UIDocumentInteractionController` should be initialize using var to make it mutable

Comment: Hi @AbhishekThapliyal thanks for your reply. I tried the above code, but it's not working.

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal actually, I used the same code what you have posted above. But the url's are coming from the collection cell did select.

Comment: @Raju: Please cross check that url is coming correctly

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal, yeah the url's are coming correctly. And also it's loading the pdf. But after two seconds its reloading continuously for three to four times and blank grey page is displaying with the file name and file size.

Comment: @Raju: may be there is other issue in your flow i guess. Cross check any kind of loop you have added or any action on scrolling

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal, clicking on collection view cell directly loading the documentation view controller. There is no looping or action in it.

Comment: If you are using presentOpenInMenu, after `presentOpenInMenu` add `interaction.presentPreview(animated: true)`.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that your file is actually pdf file by checking its extension or if url path contains ".pdf"

Otherwise it will recognize it as text file and will not open it.

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented UIDocumentInteractionController last week and it's working fine.

Do one thing declare as UIDocumentInteractionController as `var` below to class

then do allocation and initialization in `viewDidLoad()`as I did

```
documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init()
documentInteractionController?.delegate = self
```

and at the time of presenting I make it like this

```
documentInteractionController?.url = url
documentInteractionController?.presentPreview(animated: true)
```

Hope it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**(1) This issue usually occur in simulator. Check it on real device.**

If that not the case

**(2) Try this,**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

    var docController:UIDocumentInteractionController!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SamplePDF1", ofType: "pdf") { // Use if let to unwrap to fileURL variable if file exists
            docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL))

            docController.name = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL).lastPathComponent

            docController.delegate = self

            docController.presentPreviewAnimated(true)
        }


    }

    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        return self
    }
     func documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) {
        docController = nil
    }
```

Comment: Thanks  for your reply @Maddy . This issue is occurring in both iPad and iPhone as well. Actually, the above screen shot is took from my iPhone.

Comment: Then it might be memory issue.

Comment: So, how can we solve this? Is there any suggestions or need to try with any frameworks from github.

Comment: Hi @Maddy thanks for your code. But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading a file from `Bundle`, this is a known bug in iOS 11.2.x. A workaround is copying the file to tmp:

```
let docUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Doc", withExtension: "pdf")!

// copy to tmp, because there is a bug in iOS 11.2.x,
// which will make pdf in UIDocumentInteractionController blank
let temporaryDirectoryPath = NSTemporaryDirectory()
let tmpDir = URL(fileURLWithPath: temporaryDirectoryPath, isDirectory: true)
let tmpUrl = tmpDir.appendingPathComponent("Doc.pdf")
do {
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: tmpUrl.path) {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: tmpUrl)
    }
    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: docUrl, to: tmpUrl)
    let reader = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: tmpUrl)
    reader.delegate = self
    reader.presentPreview(animated: true)
} catch let error {
    print("Cannot copy item at \(docUrl) to \(tmpUrl): \(error)")
}
```

Reference: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/91835

Comment: Coping in temp dir also not work  If the file larger than 1 MB

Answer (score 0):

It does not issue with UIDocumentInteractionController.
In my case the PDF file is corrupted, that's why it is showing me the same screen.
Try to upload/open verified pdf file and you can preview same with UIDocumentInteractionController