# UIWebview show pdf with Done or Back Button

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I had an application with many internal pages running on swift3 using `UIWebView`? On moving from one page to another it shows back button, but when I click on "Download pdf" button to view pdf, it doesn't show "Back" or "Done" button after opening the pdf inside `UIWebView`. Please guide me with any possible solutions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use UIDocumentInteractionController.Please check this link, may help you https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController =[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URLOfPDF];[documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];[documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Sudhir Singh. I am getting same error inside UIWebview as referred in this link  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196066/swift-uidocumentinteractioncontroller-is-not-working". View is loaded but blank coming inside popup view. If any suggestion pls give.

Comment: Please check your PDF url is valid or not?

Comment: Url is valid. I am able to view inside my UIWebview but not inside UIDocumentInteractionController. First the PDF gets loaded and then the popup occurs with blank page as shown in the above "stack overflow" Url.